# Define variable for color and \AbsolutePosition{x, y}

Tags: variable

I have 10 files and each file has different distance variables and color variable in the code:

```
\AbsolutePosition{\x_var}{\y_var}{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [\colour_var,fill=\colour_var] (0,0) rectangle  node[text=white,text centered,rotate=270] {This is Number \Number_var} (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

I want to set variable:

- **If** *Number_var* = 1 **then** *x_var* = 5cm, *y_var* = 10cm, *colour_var* = green;
- **If** *Number_var* = 2 **then** *x_var* = 7cm, *y_var* = 11cm, *colour_var* = blue;
- **If** *Number_var* = 3 **then** *x_var* = 10cm, *y_var* = 15cm, *colour_var* = red;
- ...

and so on.

Please help me on setting variables about distance and colour, and give me an example about how I can call these variables in my code?

Thank you so much.

Comment: For the colors: `\colorlet{color1}{green}\colorlet{color2}{blue} ... ` and later use `color\numbervar` as color name.

Comment: Thanks @MartinScharrer. And Do you any idea for variable of distance? Thanks

Comment: Well, it depends a little on how `\AbsolutePosition` works, but `\expandafter\def\csname xvar1\endcsname{5cm}` ... and then use `\csname xvar\numbervar\endcsname` should work. But there are surely nicer ways to do it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer i code with your above guide: `\expandafter\def\csname xvar3 \endcsname{50cm}
\expandafter\def\csname yvar3 \endcsname{100cm} and then i call 2 method: method A (work well): \AbsolutePosition{\csname xvar3 \endcsname}{\csname yvar3 \endcsname}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [varcolor\numbervar,fill=varcolor\numbervar] (0,0) rectangle  node[text=white,text centered,rotate=270] {\textbf{\Huge \numbervar}} (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}}`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer But method B not work and notifation "File not found" (B like your above comment):  `\AbsolutePosition{\csname xvar\numbervar \endcsname}{\csname yvar\numbervar\endcsname}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [varcolor\numbervar,fill=varcolor\numbervar] (0,0) rectangle  node[text=white,text centered,rotate=270] {\textbf{\Huge \numbervar}} (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}}`. Please help for method B . Thanks

Comment: You have spaces after the number, e.g. `\def\csname xvar3 \endcsname` should be `\def\csname xvar3\endcsname`. How is `\AbsolutePosition` defined? Could you please post a full, compilable but minimal example?